# Are Other Drives Safe if I Install Pop_OS?

Tags: hard-disk, external-hdd, pop-os

I'm currently using Windows 10. I'd like to switch to Pop_OS. I have a main drive, a drive for games, a random drive, and an external drive. Would these drives be safe if I installed Pop_OS on my PC? As in, would they have to be reformatted to use? Because I obviously don't want to have to format those drives.

Comment: Welcome, they are safe as long as in the installation you select *the right disk*, and don't do any operation on the rest of them. You can unplug the external to make things easier.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense. But I won't have to format them to use them, right? And if I don't unplug them during installation, will they be harmed?

Comment: No you don't need to format them, and don't need to unplug them either.

Comment: If you are unsure and afraid of making a mistake (like choosing the wrong disk), do a backup of your data if you have the means.

Comment: Alright. Thanks. I shall try Pop_OS out in a VM, and if I like it, I'll switch.

Comment: If your games are Windows only they won't work in Linux, in that case you can do a dual boot.

Comment: Try with the live usb also, so you make sure that the drivers or other things work properly.

Comment: I'm going on an Asus motherboard, and after some research, I've found Pop_OS and Ubuntu are known to cause problems on Asus devices. So I will be using Fedora Workstation. And, except for some EA titles, all my games are through Steam. (Except for Minecraft Java Edition.) Thank you for the help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131114/discussion-between-agentlonestar007-and-schrodigerscatcuriosity).